# Why Xcode GM candidate 2 keeps crashing when debugging swift code?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am little concerned in here, I have been developing an app in Swift and I have gone through all the Xcode betas doing my best without the debugger, using `println()` like every two lines. All this hoping that soon enough some update will bring back my precious *LLDB*. But *No*. I am right now on Xcode GM candidate 2 and I am getting this:

- If I hit an exception in the app I am developing, I can't do anything else. If I try a `po` or go through  the stack trace Xcode just crashes.
- Breakpoints randomly work, but most of the time it is a Xcode crash.

Am I doing something wrong?

Is there a setting I am a missing?

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this also!

Comment: No, you are not doing anything wrong. That's "normal" (new redefinition of the "normal" term, kind of override :)). Example: I found that it systematically crashes when debugging a line having 3 or 4 custom operators

Comment: For me it crashes anywhere anytime I hit a breakpoint in swift. It doesn't matter what the code it, it could be a trivial class.

Comment: File bug reports with Apple, folks. We can commiserate here, but only Apple can fix it.

Comment: Yeah, been there, done that, but they seem to be going to /dev/null :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case on Xcode 6.1.1

I changed '`Debug Information Level`' from '`Compiler default`' to '`Line tables only`'.

It's in

> Build Settings -> Apple LLVM 6.0 - Code Generation

section

Comment: Switched to mentioned option, but debugger still crashes for me